# PHP ${$?} Could someone shed some light?

Tags: php

I'm touching up on some PHP that I sometimes forget (keep the old brain going) and came across this in a PHP questionnaire. It goes as follows:

```
<?php
$a = "b";
$b = "a";

print ${$b} ;
//$b = "b"
?>
```

How does this work and how would I use it practically? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
print ${$b}
```

It first evaluates `{$b}` and gets `'a'`.  So then it evaluates `$a` and gets `"b"` (the value stores in `$a`).

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much for clarifying for me.